# How to disable "Resize Window" shortcut (Alt-F8)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I disabled this shortcut it via System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts, but it still persists. Furthermore, it takes precedence over Alt-F8 in other apps.

How do I really disable this shortcut? Do I need a reboot after disabling it in Preferences?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? (The answer should be something like “KDE 5.3.1”, preferably with some additional indications like “under the default configuration of FooBSD, with BarDesktopManager also installed”.)

Comment: @Gilles - Gnome 2.30.2 under Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: @penguin359 - wasn't able to run ccsm yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the extra information (it's less obvious and less robust in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a restart did it.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> is handled by your window manager. In GNOME 2 (with effects enabled) the WM is Compiz. You can use the [`ccsm`](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) tool to edit its keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: How do I run ccsm? 'ccsm' itself isn't installed on my machine.

Comment: @ripper234: If it's Ubuntu, install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package.

Comment: Thanks - but when I opened ccsm, I saw that alt-f8 was really disabled there (remember, I did disable it via the built in configuration). After a system restart, this seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Run gconf-editor

Navigate to

/apps/metacity/windows_keybindings/begin_resize

and change it's value to either "" or to anything you like.

[ For safer side, you should reboot the machine ]